# Change VAT text to Sales Email

Tags: magento2, email

How can I change "VAT" with another text in the sales email? Magento 2.2.2.
Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

vendor/magento/module-tax/view/frontend/templates/order/tax.phtml or override in your theme